# Ignore CSS tags

Tags: css

Am wondering if there is a way to ignore tags:

```
<!-- I can add code here -->

<!-- I cannot edit the following start -->
<style>
     div, td {
     color: #555555;
     font-size: 10pt;
     text-align: left; 
     }
</div>
<!-- I cannot edit the following end -->

<div id="myapp" style="color:red"><div>Test</div></div>
```

Am wondering if there is anything that I can add to skip these generic div/td styles. e.g. `#myapp div { font-color: inherit; }`

Comment: @BoltClock I mean I want to ignore the generic CSS tags (After the I can add code here).

Answer (score 2):

There is no straightforward CSS method to ignore later CSS rules.

The most reliable option is to use JavaScript to remove the tag.

**Example**: Remove the, say, *first* `<style>` tag after the `<script>` element:

```
<script id="unique-id-script">
setTimeout(function() {
    var removeTheNthStyleElement = 1, found = 0,
        script = document.getElementById('unique-id-script'), elem = script;
    while (elem = elem.nextSibling) {
        if (elem.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'STYLE') {
            if (++found === removeTheNthStyleElement) {
                // Remove style element => disable styles
                elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
                // Remove temporary script element
                script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}, 4);
</script>
... anything but a style element...
<style>
/* I want to prevent these rules from being used */
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will inherit red color

```
#myapp div{
  color: inherit;
}
```